# Corona SDK removeSelf() lag

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lag

I have problem with Corona, whenever I call `removeSelf()` on item that belongs to group every other item freezes for a second and then teleports to where it should be after this time, function is called every frame

```
function moveObstacle()
  for a = 1, obstacles.numChildren, 1 do
    if obstacles[a] ~= nil then
      obstacles[a].x = obstacles[a].x - 2
      if obstacles[a].x < -50 then
          obstacles[a]:removeSelf()
      end
      if obstacles[a].addedPoint == false then
          if ball.x > obstacles[a].x then
              obstacles[a].addedPoint = true
              points = points + 1
              pointsText.text = points
          end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to remove object?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a better way.
But before that, I want to tell you that if yoy want to remove object with the removeSelf(), you need to also set it to nil.

Example:

```
object:removeSelf()
object = nil
```

But there is a very better way that I use and you should too:

```
display.remove( object )
```

You can use display.remove() for only display objects.

See [this documentation.](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/remove.html%20this%20documentation.)